# How do I force Hue to run blocks of code in sequence?

Tags: hive, hue

I am having some issues with Hue, running multiple tables generated in sequence, where Hue executes each block either in a semi-random order, or raises errors either immediately (in the case where table 4 fetches columns from table 3), or in the middle of execution, due to a myriad of errors, apparently.

Example:

```
create table table_1
<table code>;
```

```
create table table_2
<table code>;
```

```
create table table_3
<table code>;
```

```
create table table_4
<table code
from table_3>;
```

```
create table table_5
<table code
from table_4>;
```

I ran a code of this structure just this evening, and it randomly ran the blocks for table_1 and table_3 and stopped there.

In other similar examples, I have been unable to run the code since table 3 and 4 don't exist yet, and in some cases, it runs but starts blocks in non-sequence, and hitting errors due to tables not existing, and other random errors.

Is there any way to force Hue to evaluate and execute each block strictly separately? I am running up toward 100 scripts that take between 5-30 minutes to execute, so running each script separately is not really a feasible answer, unfortunately.

Comment: i think hue runs all scripts in sequence. so, they would run one after another. However if you want to avoid such situation, you can use `create table if not exists...`.

Comment: I agree, and wherever I look most webpages state that hue does run all scripts in sequence, but the reality simply is that it doesn't for me, and my colleagues. As stated in the post, I ran a code that generates six tables. Running the code resulted in block 1 and 3 to be executed and then the execution stopped. Not in sequence, not in order.

Comment: Sometime hive takes time to apply metadata changes which means it may seem its running out of order.

Comment: Well the issue is the same regardless of what it seems to do or doesn't do. I have 5 tables I want to create in sequence, I run the code, and HUE generates tables 1 and 3, i.e I am unable to achieve what I want :(

Comment: hue has issues in running all scripts so there is a good chance it will miss some. I would highly recommend to use command line and script to do these kind of batch operations. Hue is built for  running Sql to fetch/analyze data